# Could japanese Oni integrate into human civilization?

Tags: japanese, monsters, giants

Is there a case in Japanese mythology of an Oni (Big Ogre from a desolate place) willingly helping people or being a inhabitant of a village? If not why can they not integrate into human society? What forces them to live far from civilization?

TL;DR Japanese ogres - Why can't they just be like normal people?

Comment: changed the question a bit.

Comment: OK, so Oni are evil? why? probably needs a new question.

Comment: There was a myth that Benkei the monk was the result of either a demon or rape by a holy man. Benkei was called an Oniwaka (demon child). Given how famous he was as Yoshitsune's retainer, then might answer your question.